# in hbs page , while trying to access value of gender, it shows error as page not found,

Tags: node.js, user-management

in hbs page , while trying to access value of gender, it shows error as page not found,
Gender

Male
    



        Female

Gender

Male
    



        Female
    
 
without this code, program runnung fine, so tried :       , its showing the page, but the output (select gender radio button) is not as per the condition